# Kafka 0.9.0.1: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain

Tags: apache-kafka

I am [this official Kafka tutorial](http://kafka.apache.org/07/quickstart.html) to install and test kafka on Ubuntu.
First, I downloaded Kafka 0.9.0.1 from here: http://ftp.cixug.es/apache/kafka/0.9.0.1/kafka-0.9.0.1-src.tgz

Then, from kafka-0.9.0.1-src, I runned this command:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

and got the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain
```

Maybe the problem is that I upgraded my Kafka from 0.8 to 0.9.0.1, and I have previously installed ZooKeeper using `sudo apt-get install zookeeperd`.
To remove previous version of Kafka, I just deleted a directory with an old version using `rm -rf kafka-0.8`. Should I uninstall/install something else to be able to use Kaka-0-9-0-1?

Comment: This is a duplicate thread.
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117080/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-config-zookeeper-properties/38119930#38119930

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the source package. Download the [binary](http://ftp.cixug.es/apache/kafka/0.9.0.1/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1.tgz) package of Kafka and do testing.

Comment: So, I newly installed Kafka 0.8 and it works fine. Don't get the point why this happens