# Kafka Error: Could not find or load main class .home.kafka.kafka.config.server.properties

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04), but when I try to start Kafka with this command I get an error:

```
kafka@vertica-2:~$ ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties

Error: Could not find or load main class .home.kafka.kafka.config.server.properties
```

Comment: That is weird. The error indicates, that the script tries to use your server.properties file as a Java class. Can you debug the script by execution it via `bash -x ~/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties` and add the output to your question?

Comment: You can see your answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38264396/6768729)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you downloaded the bin version, not the uncompiled source(unless you compile it yourself). This error will happen when trying to start the server from uncompiled source.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Java version to be compatible with particular Kafka build. You can use below link to update your Java version:

[https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-openjdk-14-on-centosfedora-linux/#:~:text=Visit%20JDK%2014%20releases%20page%20to%20download%20the%20latest%20archive.&text=Extract%20the%20downloaded%20OpenJDK%2014%20archive%20file%20using%20tar%20command.&text=Move%20the%20resulting%20folder%20to%20%2Fopt%20directory.&text=Confirm%20Java%20version](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-openjdk-14-on-centosfedora-linux/#:%7E:text=Visit%20JDK%2014%20releases%20page%20to%20download%20the%20latest%20archive.&text=Extract%20the%20downloaded%20OpenJDK%2014%20archive%20file%20using%20tar%20command.&text=Move%20the%20resulting%20folder%20to%20%2Fopt%20directory.&text=Confirm%20Java%20version).