# Unable to run zookeeper server

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have recently installed `kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0`, but to run this we have to first run the zookeeper server.

But whenever I run command

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

it throws an error i.e.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.bin....logs.zookeeper-gc.log
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: are you running it on windows?

Comment: no , running on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117080/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-config-zookeeper-properties